# Jenkins schedule agent node availability

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

We have a number of machines that we would like to use as agent nodes for Jenkins, but only in certain time intervals (i.e. not during working hours).  Is it possible to configure an agent node  to be used as a agent for builds in particular time range?  For example:  a  M-F from 10pm - 5am, Sat and Sun all day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the **slave configuration panel**, select **`Take this slave on-line according to a schedule`**.

You can then specify the startup time and the desired uptime for the slave.

You must be **careful with long-running jobs** though -- if a three hour job is scheduled to the slave one minute before the uptime expires, then the job will continue running for the entire period, since **Jenkins will not terminate running builds** after the scheduled end time.

Comment: Whoops, how did I miss that option?  Thanks!