# Jenkins : bring the node online/offline automatically

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I want to bring my node online/offline automatically in Jenkins but I don't know how to do. I know cron conf for agent is possible but i can't use it because we have a global policy on this setting. So is there a way to bring node online/offline automatically in Jenkins please

I need it because I need to run a pipeline on specific agent which is offline in major of time ;)

Comment: See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466900/jenkins-schedule-slave-node-availability)

Comment: Thank you, I'm reading this post. I think it will be help me :)

Comment: I think this post talk about availability conf in slave node but I can't use it due to general policy on script :/ I need to use temporarly offline/online action bu automatically :)

Comment: Explain this global policy/general policy constraint.